# how to let android framework to instantiate a fragment that have a constructor parameter in save instance state

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have added a fragment in another fragment
in this way

```
Secondfragment secondFragment=new SecondFragment(parmater);

fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(fragmentContainerView.getId(),
                secondFragment, null)
        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
        .commit();
```

the firstFragment is containing the fragmentContainerView and it's inside a ViewPager2 with other fragments
after changing the page and return to it again the app is crashes and give me the error
Unable to instantiate fragment , as I mentioned this because the firstFragment have a parameter in constructor .
I use this way in multiple places .

after changing the page the first fragment is been in the onPause state and after I go to the first fragment again its recreate the views and the proplen happen here , it cannot instantiate the second fragment.

I want a way to let it instantiate it again ,or any better idea and thank you in advance .

Comment: Does this answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment

Comment: @dominicoder helpful, it gives me the start of the road.